# TextBlock doesn't want to adjust grid columns

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, width, textblock

I'm preparing control to present some data. It is built in the following way:

```
-> ScrollViewer
--> StackPanel
---> Border
----> Grid
---> Border
----> Grid
...
---> Border
----> Grid
```

And there is my code for each item

```
    public class PresenterItem : Border
{
    // Variables
    private Submission submission;
    private int index;

    private Grid grid = new Grid();

    // Constructor
    public PresenterItem(int i, Submission subm)
    {
        index = i;
        submission = subm;
        Child = grid;

        Background = Global.GET_BRUSH("ItemBackground");
        CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(5);
        Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 10);
        Padding = new Thickness(5);

        grid.ShowGridLines = true;


        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(40, GridUnitType.Pixel) });
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star) });
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star) });

        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(40, GridUnitType.Pixel) });
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(30, GridUnitType.Pixel) });
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });

        InsertContent();
    }

    private Label CreateLabel(int row, int column, string content, int columnSpan = 1)
    {
        Label newLabel = new Label();
        newLabel.Content = content;

        Grid.SetRow(newLabel, row);
        Grid.SetColumn(newLabel, column);
        Grid.SetColumnSpan(newLabel, columnSpan);

        grid.Children.Add(newLabel);

        return newLabel;
    }
    private TextBlock CreateTextBlock(int row, int column, int columnSpan = 1)
    {
        TextBlock newTextBlock = new TextBlock();
        newTextBlock.Foreground = Brushes.Silver;

        Grid.SetRow(newTextBlock, row);
        Grid.SetColumn(newTextBlock, column);
        Grid.SetColumnSpan(newTextBlock, columnSpan);

        grid.Children.Add(newTextBlock);

        return newTextBlock;
    }

    private void InsertContent()
    {
        // Number
        Label number = CreateLabel(0, 0, $"#{index + 1}");
        number.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        number.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        number.FontSize = 17;

        // Header
        Label header = CreateLabel(0, 1, $"{submission.Name} ({submission.Rank})");
        header.Foreground = Global.GET_BRUSH("HeaderForeground");
        header.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        header.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        header.FontSize = 17;

        // Timestamp
        TextBlock timestamp = CreateTextBlock(0, 2);
        timestamp.Inlines.Add(new Run("Timestamp"));
        timestamp.Inlines.Add(new Run($"{submission.Timestamp}") { Foreground = Global.GET_BRUSH("HeaderForeground") });

        timestamp.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
        timestamp.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        timestamp.FontSize = 13.5;

        // Range
        TextBlock range = CreateTextBlock(1, 1);
        range.Inlines.Add(new Run("Some text "));
        range.Inlines.Add(new Run($"{submission.Range.ToStringWithDayNames()}") { Foreground = Global.GET_BRUSH("HeaderForeground") });

        range.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        range.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        range.Margin = new Thickness(5, 0, 0, 0);
        range.FontSize = 13.5;

        // Conflict
        Label conflict = CreateLabel(1, 2, "Nie wykryto konfliktu");
        conflict.Foreground = Global.GET_BRUSH("GreenForeground");
        conflict.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
        conflict.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        conflict.FontSize = 13.5;

        // Content
        TextBlock content = CreateTextBlock(2, 1, 2);
        content.Inlines.Add(new Run($"{submission.Content}"));

        cotent.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        content.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        content.Margin = new Thickness(5, 0, 0, 0);
        content.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.WrapWithOverflow;
        content.FontSize = 13.5;
    }
```

[How it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKS9k.png)

It perfectly works but when I added last TextBlock whole control is stretching to the right. In designer the same way of creating elements works, but in code no. What am I doing wrong?

I would like to achieve this effect with column 1 and 2 with the same width everywhere.
[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUMz4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dealt with this problem on my own. If someone will be having the same problem like me, I will write how to repair it.

In the place where my app initializes `ScrollViewer` I set property `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` to `Hidden`. After setting this property to `Disabled` everything starts to work correctly.

There is something about this:
https://crmdev.wordpress.com/2010/01/16/how-to-deal-with-stubborn-silverlight-a-k-a-stubborn-me/

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the dependency property [Grid.IsSharedSizeScope](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.grid.issharedsizescope?view=netframework-4.8) to true in the StackPanel and then set the Property [SharedSizeGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.definitionbase.sharedsizegroup?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Controls_DefinitionBase_SharedSizeGroup) for every ColumnDefinition to a string that definies the group with same size.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This property repairs problem with columns' width in grids, but how to make text block wrap at the end of third column instead of stretching all to the right without any limits?

Comment: Set 'Row.Height' to auto and set [TextBlock.TextWrapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textblock.textwrapping?view=netframework-4.8) to 'Wrap'